# Xamarin return index of an observableCollection bind with listview

Tags: xamarin

How can I get the index of an observableCollection that is bind to a list ?

I want when a user click on a button on a listview or collectionView , that button command paramater return the index of clicked list cell.

Command method :

```
    private void HT(object id)
    {

        var x = (id as CategoriesGroup);

        int si = ExpandedCategories.IndexOf(x);

        Debug.WriteLine("TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPPPPPPPPPPPEEEEEEEED");
    }
```

XAML code

```
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ExpandedCategories}" IsGrouped="True">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"></GridItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label Text="{Binding NameNative}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title"></Label>
                        <Button Image="{Binding StateIcon}"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                BorderColor="Transparent"
                                BorderWidth="0"
                                Command="{Binding BindingContext.ExpandCommand ,Source={x:Reference ServiceListPage}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

For first item taped i get 0 as index which is correct , for the rest I get -1

Comment: use the `IndexOf` method to find the index - there is not really a direct way to get the index without using a custom collection

Comment: @Jason I used indexOf , the probelm im facing is the first item return 0 which is correct ,the rest of the items return -1

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: @Cheesebaron no does not :(

Comment: @Jason https://www.codepile.net/pile/EegEJAK8

Comment: @Jason         private void HT(object id)

Comment: @Jason https://www.codepile.net/pile/yDJkXw8r XAML

Comment: @Jason what im trying to do is expand and collapse list headers like an accordian

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question and not as an off-site resource

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added relevant code

Comment: @Jason I added relevant code

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through HT and see why the IndexOf is failing?

Comment: @Jason yes ,i did .. For first item taped i get 0 as index which is correct , for the rest I get -1.

Comment: did you actually look at the contents of `ExpandedCategories` and verify that it contained the item you are looking for?  Is there a reason you are using object and casting instead of just using the proper type everywhere?

Comment: @Jason yes I looked into the content of ExpandedCategories and I verified it that it contained the item.\

Comment: @Jason  I am trying to make an accordion . I am expanding the collectionView grouping example from the official docs .

Comment: @Jason I have two lists : one list contain all my items , second list contain only items that are expanded (bool = true) . and the collectionView is bind to the expaneded list.

Comment: @Jason what do you mean use proper type everywhere ?
this is a command paramater. the Object id is passed from a button , and that is the command paramater

Comment: use `CategoriesGroup` instead of `object`

Comment: @Jason i did , more testing shows the first item i click return the correct index, if i clicked on another header it return -1 .. ill keep digging into this issue .